# Synchronize redundant mongoid documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, graph, mongoid, data-synchronization, redundancy

I have decided to modelise a knowledge graph with one node = one document, and one edge = one embedded document in a node. This graph supports oriented edges, and I have decided to duplicate an edge in both nodes when it is bidirectional.

```
class Tag
  includes Mongoid::Document
  field :name  

  embeds_many :links, class_name: 'TagLink', inverse_of: :parent_node

class TagLink
  includes Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :parent_node, class_name: 'Tag', inverse_of: :link
  belongs_to :child_node, class_name: 'Tag'
```

Now my user moderator can create new tags, and specify links for this tag.

The parameters in my POST/PATCH request look like this

```
tag: {name: "Rails", links: [
  {child_name: "Ruby", child_node: "abhkdfjgksgdf000023d415", bidirectional_edge: true, ...}, 
  {child_name: "Server Programming", bidirectional_edge: true, ...}
]}
```

What would be the best way to ensure the synchronization is done well ? I'm not sure of the behaviour I really want, but basically **the above POST should**

- Create a new tag "Rails"
- Update the tags "Ruby", "Server Programming" to add links to "Ruby", because the `bidirectional_edge` is set to true
- If there is a problem in the update of links, maybe the ideal would be to rollback any changes and show the view with errors (if rollbacks are too difficult, then maybe just show a list of problems)

I am currently trying to roll my own implementation, but maybe you have any gems, tips, or you can figure this out faster and cleaner than I would do